# putting csv column into an array

Tags: php, csv

I've got a csv with column headers: description, stock, mfgid  (and some other headers I don't need).

I need to get the data from the column headers stock and mfgid in an array.

I was using fgetcsv() but it was putting the entire row into an exclusive key in the array.

found this here at stackoverflow but can't get it to work right:

```
$file = fopen('inventory.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
  print_r($line);
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: what is the exact problem? what is shown? what's not working?

Answer (score 2):

For reading in a complete CSV file use this construct:

```
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file("inventory.csv"));
$header = array_shift($csv);
```

This separates the `$header` into a separate array from the rest of the `$csv` data.

If you then (seemingly?) want a map of two fields, try:

```
$col1 = array_search("stock" $headers);
$col2 = array_search("mfgid", $headers);
foreach ($csv as $row) {
     $map[ $row[$col1] ] = $row[$col2]; }
```

This would give you a `stock` -> `mfgid` array.

Comment: Well it may work for others, but my server is not using php 5.3 so I think that limits me to not being able to use "str_getcsv"

Comment: Ah okay. You can try one of the emulations on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#98088 or use http://upgradephp.berlios.de/ to get this PHP5.3 function. But you could use your old loop method and just apply the second code block for separating the columns